# How to recursively extract files from nested folder structure into a parent folder

Tags: file, directory, copy, extract, dacapo

I have a problem in which I have a directory called psp (level 0)
full of a bunch of folders (level 1)
each containing two or three folders (level 4)
Containing a couple of .pseudo files (they are just text files) and a .tar.gz file.

The program I want to run (dacapo) needs to have all of those .pseudo files in the psp directory.

Hence, I need somehow get all the .pseudo files into that directory.

I should note that the whole file structure started out as a .tar.gz file. You can find it here: http://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/dacapo-files/campos-dacapo-pseudopotentials-1.tar.gz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your in a unix environment, you could try something like

```
for m in `find . -name '*.pseudo'`;do cp $m ./psp;done
```

For further debugging purposes, you can put echo in front of "cp" and you'd see what commands would get run - in a sort of dry run...

Comment: For the record, my psp directory is in /opt/dacapo. That seemed to work fine. Thank you for answering--that saved me a LOT of time!